# Choppy video playback on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, video, playback

I'm experiencing a weird video stuttering, on any video I play, be on youtube, vlc, mpc, If on youtube, it doesn't matter if I'm on firefox or chromium, at 140p or 4k, the problem is exactly the same, once every 5 seconds or so, the video playback just stop for a second, then resume.

I don't see any stuttering on visual effects on the desktop as of scrolling, moving windows, etc.

I run dual boot, I don't have such problem on windows.

Specs:
Ryzen 5 2600, nvidia gtx 1650 Super, 16GB ram, SSD drive
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
The system is never overloaded

What I've tried:

- Changing video drivers: nouveau, nvidia 440, nvidia 450
- Installing codecs, ubuntu-restricted-extras
- Disabling hardware acceleration on programs
- Swapping from kubuntu to ubuntu
- Fresh installing ubuntu

I've searched other topics and tried their solutions, but none seem to be the same problem.. Can anybody help? I can provide more information if needed